# Python 3 on executing list creation do not work properly

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

I try to create a list in python from the analysis of a Numpy array but the creation with my for cycles do not create the entire list.
In fact I have w=404 and h=481 and I use range function to create the list:

```
true_label = []
for i in range(0,w*h):
    if np.all(image_array[i] == [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]): # red
        true_label.append(0)
    if np.all(image_array[i] == [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]): # gree
        true_label.append(1)
    if np.all(image_array[i] == [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]): # red
        true_label.append(2)
```

But at the end of execution my list has 193920 elements instead of 194324.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Just a side note you might want to fix those comments... two of those aren't going to both be red :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following edit of your code:

```
true_label = []
for i in range(0,w*h):
    if np.all(image_array[i] == [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]): # red
        true_label.append(0)
    else if np.all(image_array[i] == [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]): # gree
        true_label.append(1)
    else if np.all(image_array[i] == [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]): # red
        true_label.append(2)
    else:
      true_label.append(3)
```

Then, count the number of "3". I would bet that there are 404 "3".